How to verify with a tool that comparisons should not be made with None when you know that a variable is always a list?
I'm working on a Python project and I want to make sure that no unnecessary or incorrect comparisons are made in my code. In particular, I have the following code:
def my_func() -> list:
    return []

a = my_func()

if a is not None:
    # do something

In this case, my_func always returns a list (never None), so the if a is not None comparison seems redundant and will not have the expected behavior because if condition will enter. I know that instead I should use:
if a and len(a) > 0:
    # do something

My goal is to find a way to verify that these wrong comparisons are not made. I've considered tools like flake8 and mypy, but I'm not sure how to configure them to identify these cases.
Is there a way to configure flake8 or mypy or any other tool to identify comparisons like if a is not None: when a is known to always be a list?
i wrote a flake8 plugin, but i want to know if this kind of stuff are managed by some tool

For the record, you should never use if a and len(a) > 0:; it's definitionally redundant. Python's rule for the truthiness of collections is "False if the collection is empty/length 0, true otherwise". So if a: is exactly equivalent to if len(a) > 0: for any collection that obeys the normal Python rules (you'd have to work to make it not obey the rules; a class with __len__ defined will follow these rules unless __bool__ is also defined in a way that changes that default), and would only differ in that, if it's not a collection, the len(a) would raise a TypeError.

Mypy does have something for this: --strict-equality and comparison-overlap. This duo won't work for your specific case, however, since comparisons with None are allowed as a special case.
a: list[int]

# Caught:
# Non-overlapping container check (...)  [comparison-overlap]
if 'this is a string' in a: ...

# Uncaught, unless you also use `--warn-unreachable`.
if a is None: ...

# Completely "fine".
if a is not None: ...

There are a few years-old open issues about this: #8294, #11888, #14541.

Pyright found the problem:

Condition will always evaluate to True since the types "list[int]" and "None" have no overlap  (reportUnnecessaryComparison)

Try it on the Pyright Playground
Note: I made some changes to your code to remove some irrelevant errors (missing code in if-block and unparameterized list), and in the process I realized the function isn't really needed, so this is what I ended up with:
a: list[int] = []

if a is not None:
    pass  # do something


I have no idea why the two downvotes. Any feedback is appreciated.
